# Netty in a Java applet going through a proxy server

Tags: netty

We use Netty in a Java applet to talk to a tomcat server.  This works perfectly.

We have a user who has configured a proxy server in Internet Explorer.  The web page and Java applet get served up, but when Netty tries to connect, bypasses the proxy server and does a direct connection; this fails because the user has a firewall set up to prevent direct connections; all client connections must go through the proxy server.

Is there a way to have Netty use the proxy server configured in the browser?

Comment: Here's a tip: use Firefox/Chrome, and get rid of IE. (If you are using IE for the efficiency and speed, you should use Chrome (that's what they copied))

Comment: Is it possible to access the browser's proxy configuration from an Applet? If not, we can't and the applet has to provide its own configuration method.

Comment: I tried FireFox but no difference.  This was not a real option anyway, since we must support all browsers.

Comment: Trustin:
Sorry for delayed response.  I was watching the main page and saw 0 answers and thought that meant 0 replies.
I can access the proxy settings from the browser in the applet.  Do I need only to set the following System properties?:
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort+"");
Thanks.

Comment: I can get the proxy information in the applet.  How do I supply it to the applet?

Comment: Sorry. I can get the proxy information in the applet. How do I supply it to Netty?